# Align centered list

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists

I am trying to write a list that is nicely aligned, but am having problems. 
Right now my list is coded like this:

```
\begin{mylist}
\caption{List of countries that consume the most coffee per capita
\cite{stats}}\label{percap}
\begin{enumerate}
\centering
\item Finland: 12 kg
\item Norway: 9.9 kg
\item Iceland: 9 kg
\item Denmark: 8.7 kg
\item Netherlands: 8.4 kg
\end{enumerate}
\end{mylist}
```

Which looks like this:
[image]

However, I would like the numbers (1,2,3..) to be aligned, but I would still like the list centered.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! As we can't read in your mind, how is the `mylist` environment defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Ian, I use a `minipage`, but here calculate the proper width of it, based on the widest label.  (I also used `table` because `mylist` was not provided)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{List of countries that consume the most coffee per capita
\cite{stats}}\label{percap}
\centering
\medskip
\setbox0=\hbox{Netherlands: 8.4 kg}% Widest entry
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\wd0+\labelwidth+\labelsep}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Finland: 12 kg
\item Norway: 9.9 kg
\item Iceland: 9 kg
\item Denmark: 8.7 kg
\item Netherlands: 8.4 kg
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A solution with `eqparbox` and `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \fbox{\begin{eqminipage}{CL}%
      \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=1.33em, itemsep=0pt]
        \item Finland: 12 kg
        \item Norway: 9.9 kg
        \item Iceland: 9 kg
        \item Denmark: 8.7 kg
        \item Netherlands: 8.4 kg
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{eqminipage}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does the `CL` stand for in the argument to `eqminipage`? Is it country list? Also, why the `1.33em` for `leftmargin` in the `enumerate` option.? Was it derived visually for evenness or is it some default value?

Comment: @chandra: `CL` is just a tag – all eqparboxes sharing the same tag will have the width of the widest of them. It just stands here for `Centred List`. Also `1.33em` because the standard `leftmargin=*`  results in problems (some form of partial incompatibility of eqparbox with enumitem?), and this values solved the problem while producing the same spacing between item number and item body.

Comment: Thanks, @Bernard. One more question please. If I comment out the `center` environment, I find that the file does not compile. While I realize that the OP wanted it centered, I was just curious why removing the centering would cause an error message and such failure.

Comment: That is very strange for me… Note that, replacing center with`flushleft` or `flushright`, it compiles fine. It seems indeed linked to the list environment, since the error message mentions `\@itemlabel` as Undefined control sequence.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a minipage.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Finland: 12 kg
\item Norway: 9.9 kg
\item Iceland: 9 kg
\item Denmark: 8.7 kg
\item Netherlands: 8.4 kg
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```